# Abandoned css linear transition function?

Tags: css, css-transitions

In [MDN References for CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition), there is a line in the grammar section referring to a transition that is named linear but takes arguments.

```
<linear-easing-function> = 
  linear( <linear-stop-list> )
```

But I could not find any documentation or example of using it anywhere online. Is it possible that it's just in CSS grammar, but it's not implemented in the engine for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a draft, part of [CSS Easing Functions Level 2](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-easing-2/#the-linear-easing-function). It’s [only implemented in Firefox Nightly so far](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/7533).